# bubble tooltip with dynamic data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php $this->baseUrl()?>/public/js/jQuery.bubbletip-1.0.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="<?php $this->baseUrl()?>/public/js/bubbletip/bubbletip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(i=1;i<12;i++){
    $('#a'+i).bubbletip($('#tip'+i), { deltaDirection: 'right' });
    }
});
</script>
```

code in header part

```
   <?php 
    foreach($this->nominations as $nomination)
            {
        for($i=1;$i<12;$i++){
        if($nomination['award'.$i]!=""){?>
        <div id="tip<?php echo $i?>" style="display:none;">
            <div class="star"><strong><?php echo $nomination['award'.$i];?></strong></div>
            <div><strong>Project: </strong><?php echo $nomination['project'.$i]?></div>
        </div>
     <?php }}
for($i=1;$i<12;$i++){
                    if($nomination['award'.$i]!=""){
                echo "<span id='a$i'>";
                echo "<img src='/public/assets/images/icons/star.png'/>";
                echo "</span>"; 
                }}

}?>
```

code in body section

My problem is when take my mouse over the stars of first iteration of `foreach` everything is working fine but its not working from second iteration i found that problem is with id a,tip becuause they are always becoming a1,a2.. and tip1,tip2... is there any solution

Comment: whenever we reached second turn of foreach loop every $i is becoming 1 and in header part the first values are taking preference while reading with id and it is working for first turn of foreach loop and remaining times also same ids are repeating that's why its not working from second turn because of id conflict

Comment: can you share URL where this is happening? Coz I m not clear what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because every iteration of your forach loop creating elements of same id from a1 t a12 
you need to put another level in names of ids .Try to use following

```
<?php
$count=0;
    foreach($this->nominations as $nomination)
            {
            $count++;
        for($i=1;$i<12;$i++){
        if($nomination['award'.$i]!=""){?>
        <div id="tip<?php echo $i?>_<?php echo $count?>" style="display:none;">
            <div class="star"><strong><?php echo $nomination['award'.$i];?></strong></div>
            <div><strong>Project: </strong><?php echo $nomination['project'.$i]?></div>
        </div>
     <?php }}
for($i=1;$i<12;$i++){
                    if($nomination['award'.$i]!=""){
                echo "<span id='a$i_$count'>";
                echo "<img src='/public/assets/images/icons/star.png'/>";
                echo "</span>"; 
                }}

}
<input type="hidden" id="total_iteration" name="total_iteration" value="<?php echo $count?>"/>
?>
```

And change you javascript code accordingly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var total=$('#total_iteration').val();
var t=0;
 for(t=1;t<total;t++)
 {

    for(i=1;i<12;i++){
    $('#a'+i+'_t').bubbletip($('#tip'+i+'_'+t), { deltaDirection: 'right' });
    }

    }
});
</script>
```

After some debigging above code should run the  way you want i haven't tested it but i guess the main problme is the elements of duplicate ids in each foreach iteration

Comment: it will work fine by adding additional two lines of code for checking of project existence otherwise it will throw an error